# String To Hex and Hex to String

Tags: vb.net, hex

I am able to convert my string to hex value but unable to do the opposite method:

```
Public Function StringToHex(_str$)
    Return BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(_str$))
End Function

Public Function HexToString(_str$)
  'could not do this
End Function

Private Sub Button55_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button55.Click
   lblStatus.Text = StringToHex("mankat236598")
   'result : 99-A9-E4-6A-DD-B7-EB-9F-7C

   lblInfo.Text = HexToString( lblStatus.Text)
    'i want result : mankat236598
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have a string representation of bytes in a format "00-00-00", you need to convert the "00" etc. to bytes. You can skip the dashes while doing that:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Function StringToHex(s As String) As String
        Return BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(s))
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Convert hex string to bytes and then Base64 encode those bytes.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="hexString">Hex as a string with dashes between bytes, e.g. A0-10-FF.</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Function HexToString(hexString As String) As String
        Dim nBytes = (hexString.Length + 1) \ 3
        Dim bb(nBytes - 1) As Byte

        For i = 0 To nBytes - 1
            Dim b = hexString.Substring(i * 3, 2)
            bb(i) = Convert.ToByte(b, 16)
        Next

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(bb, Base64FormattingOptions.None)

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Dim testString = "mankat236598"
        Dim x = StringToHex(testString)
        Console.WriteLine(x)

        Dim y = HexToString(x)

        ' Check if the result is correct:
        If y <> testString Then Console.WriteLine("Round-trip failure.")

        Console.WriteLine(y)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```